# ObjectParameter: Passing Value vs Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image]

When should we pass a Value and when should we pass a Type to the constructor of ObjectParameter and why?

When attempting to get a SQL OUTPUT value out of a stored procedure, it does not appear to make a difference passing a value of 0,1,2 etc or typeof(long) for example.

```
var ob = new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", typeof(long));
// or new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", 0)
// both work
db.InsertCustomer(ob, "CustomerName");
var CustomerID = ob.Value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the information you have available when you are calling the constructor.  All 3, name, value and type, are available as properties of the object and can be set later in the code.

It is possible that you need to create the parameter object, you know the name, and type, but you may have the value at a later time. In that case you can call the [ObjectParameter(String, Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301079(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor.

If you have the name and value when creating the object, then [ObjectParameter(String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357240(v=vs.110).aspx) could be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ob = new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", typeof(long));
var ob2 = new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", 0);
```

Shouldn't be the same as one is an `int` and one is a `long`.

In your case, where you are getting data out, it won't matter if you use a type of a value. However using a type makes it more verbose, easier to read, and easier to understand in my opinion. It can prevent any mistakes such as int vs long.